# Steam missing the following 32-bit libraries : libc.so.6

Tags: steam, 32-bit

I installed Steam through the Ubuntu Logitec and got the following messages:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libc.so.6

Some people advised in previous threads to download through the [Steam website](http://www.steampowered.com) and I did but it remains the same.

I am not familiar with Ubuntu yet so pardon my basic question.

Processor: [Intel® Core™ i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAAahUKEwihhIOkk67IAhVIMj4KHV2zDAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fark.intel.com%2Fproducts%2F81016%2FIntel-Core-i5-4210U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz&usg=AFQjCNFj9Zko_YdRrMrKxoWQILEZmzLYrg&sig2=UPcG-CskozVKMsCZGzz25g)
Graphic card: [Intel® Haswell Mobile](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiClbmzk67IAhXD2T4KHSoiCww&url=http%3A%2F%2Fark.intel.com%2Fproducts%2Fcodename%2F42174%2FHaswell&usg=AFQjCNGboTOQJfcTeWpXCpqte64iAIxr8w&sig2=Bc-5CowXKEEHas1pcDuiMQ)
OS: [Ubuntu (Please Specify Flavour) 64 bits](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing those following `libgl` libraries :

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6-i386
```

You may need to add the 32-bit architecture first :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```